# "If" doesn´t work - weird string formatting

Tags: php, xml, formatting

I have weird problem with data handling. I need to pick data from the user form, and handle it (generate xml).
The data is for example this:

2000;AC;1;60;5;5;Do your setup      - meaning voltage, voltage type, test current, test time, ramp-up time, rampdown time, and user prompt.

I want to decide how to assemble my xml file based on the last value. If it is zero, there will be shorter xml assembly, while when there is text, there will be user prompt assembly of xml taggery.

So I explode the input into array, and check the value by:

```
If (empty($xplodline[6]) == true) {do this;}
else {do that;}
```

The problem is, that it always only does "that", and never "this", even when there is 0 in the $xplodline[6] as intended.

So I put echo $xplodline[6]; into {do that;} to see what´s happening.
The zero is echoed, (and while this action is in the cycle, I get other $xplodline[6]s from the cycle), and I see there is a space between the zero in the $xplodline[6] and next $xplodline[6] iteration. When I look into user form or temporary cleaned file with these values, there is no space between. Where could it come from?

When I put another array divider into the user form to make it ;0; there is no space, and If statement works well.

Here is the original data from the temporary cleaned file:

```
2000;AC;1;60;5;5;0
2000;AC;1;60;5;5;Set your cables for X10
2000;AC;1;60;5;5;Set your cables for X10
```

Any idea?

Ok, here is the code:

```
$stringer = fopen($tempfile, "r");
while(!feof($stringer)){
$oneline = fgets($stringer) ;
$xplodline = explode(";",$oneline) ;
$range01 = "gross" ;
$rampup = "100" ;
$rampdown = "100" ;
$rampupfunction = "false" ;
$rampdownfunction = "false" ;
$currentrange = "_1mA" ;
$assy01 = "1" ;
if ($xplodline[0] >= 3000) {$range01 = "gross" ;}
else {$range01 = "klein" ;}
if (empty($xplodline[4]) == false) {$rampupfunction = "true" ; $rampup = round($xplodline[0] / $xplodline[4]) ;}
if (empty($xplodline[5]) == false) {$rampdownfunction = "true" ;$rampdown = round($xplodline[0] / $xplodline[5]) ;}
if ($xplodline[2] < 1) {$currentrange = "_1mA";}
if ($xplodline[2] >= 1 && $xplodline[2] < 10) {$currentrange = "_10mA";}
if ($xplodline[2] >= 10 && $xplodline[2] < 100) {$currentrange = "_100mA";}
if (empty($xplodline[6]) == true) {$assy01 = $xmltestbegin.$xplodline[0]."V ".$xplodline[1].$xmltype.$xplodline[1].$xmlrange.$range01.$xmlrampup.$rampupfunction.$xmlrampdown.$rampdownfunction.$xmlcurrentrange.$currentrange.$xmlvoltage.$xplodline[0].$xmlrampupspeed.$rampup.$xmlrampdownspeed.$rampdown.$xmltesttime.$xplodline[3].$xmlcurrent.$xplodline[2].$xmlballast ;}
else {$assy01 = $xmlpromptbegin.$xplodline[6].$xmlpromptend.$xmltestbegin.$xplodline[0]."V ".$xplodline[1].$xmltype.$xplodline[1].$xmlrange.$range01.$xmlrampup.$rampupfunction.$xmlrampdown.$rampdownfunction.$xmlcurrentrange.$currentrange.$xmlvoltage.$xplodline[0].$xmlrampupspeed.$rampup.$xmlrampdownspeed.$rampdown.$xmltesttime.$xplodline[3].$xmlcurrent.$xplodline[2].$xmlballast ;}
file_put_contents ( $filename, $assy01, FILE_APPEND );  
}
fclose($stringer);
```

My function works ok, every If except the last one, works...

Comment: too much text, too little code....

Comment: @apokryfos `0` is empty. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php `The following things are considered to be empty:..."0" (0 as a string)`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. https://eval.in/584631

Comment: @chris85 you're right, though it's still a source of grief when there's trailing spaces involved.

Comment: Yes, var_dumping `$xplodline[6]` might prove useful.

Comment: I even tried to replace 0 with whatever symbol. For example "K", and then check if $xplodline[6] == "K";  - no change. Still not working.

Comment: Post a full example of what you have. In your example `$xplodline[6]` is undefined. In my example the code works as expected.

Comment: chris85: if you put "the original data" from my original post into $tempfile as the top line of the code - some txt file you create, it should be about complete.

Comment: I don't have time to recreate your scripts. I even took the time to re-create your example, still NOT reproducible. https://eval.in/584640 Good luck.

Comment: chris85: it´s fast here on stackoverflow, I see :-) There is bootload of stuff going on in my scripts, and the code would be endless. @no solution to this. I´m not asking about the if function, but rather where does space come from in the array.

Comment: Would `empty(trim($xplodline[6]))) == true` work? Again, it would have been much quicker if you dumped the contents of the `$xplodline` array

Comment: apokryfos: trim worked. Thanks! by dumping, you mean echo, or file_put_contents?

Comment: The short answer for the cause of your problem is that `fgets` will always include the newline characters in the returned string.

Comment: apokryfos: Oh, I see. The contents of xplodline is changing, because the string is in the cycle. But you can see what data is in the xplodline cycles. It is marked as "original data" in my original post.  // Yes, I thought it will be something like new line characters. I tried to strip it down from the if checking of string comparison, with no luck. Trim worked, so I suppose it is the answer. Thank you @all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

In short, there's always going to be a newline character in your last array entry. Clean it up by doing

```
$oneline = rtrim(fgets($stringer));
```

You can also consider:

```
$stringer = fopen($tempfile, "r");
while(!feof($stringer)){
    $xplodline = fgetcsv($stringer,0,";"); 
    //Rest of code as normal
```

which would let PHP handle the file as a CSV style file.